# I use wordpress wp-page navi

Tags: permalinks

I am wondering if i can change the page name permalink of "site.com/page2" to be like "site.com/paginas2" , or to show only numbers like "site.com/2" .
Thank you very much .

Answer (score 0):

you can type the page name you want in the header(that will be your default permalink) if you want to have a different permalink then you can just change the permalink on the right of the edit page where it says URL slug

Comment: Thanks for the reply  , but i wanted to change the page number permalink ,the navigation  pages , where in the title says example.com.page1/ and after that is page2 and so on . I need to change page1 , page2 , to paginas1, paginas2, or simply the numbers .

Comment: then maybe try going to wp-admin/options-permalink.php and change the permalink settings to custom and type  `/%post_id%/`

Comment: the post_id is not what i am trying to change is the page name . When you have many pages on a website , they are numbered , counted , you have in the url example.com/page1,example.com/page2,example.com/page3, but instead of the word page i want to put " paginas" or let simply the number .